# can I have widget appear in single post for specific category

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

i would like to have a sidebar appear in a single posts for a specific category. I not great at php so this is what i have been able to come up with. It does not work of course lol. Your help will be very much appreciated!

```
    <?php if( in_category('9') ) : ?>
    <div>
    <h1>Other Products I Recommend</h1>
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('products2')) : ?>
    [ do default stuff if no widgets ]
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>`
```

Comment: You going to need to explain a bit more, and maybe try troubleshooting before you can get a good answer.  Where does the code fail?  Do you see the `<h1>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for that:

1. There is a plugin that can help you with this. It's called jetpack. When it is installed and activated, when you add any widget to a sidebar there will be a visibility option, click that and choose which pages/categories/etc to show the widget it.
2. Code:

As for your code:

```
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('products2')) : ?>
```

that says if the dynamic_sidebar function doesn't exists or if it's not the products2 sidebar then do X. That function will exist as sidebars are set in that function, so nothing inside that if statement will run.

You will want something like:

```
<?php if( in_category('9') ) : ?>
<div>
<h1>Other Products I Recommend</h1>
<?php dynamic_sidebar('products2'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

that should display the contents of what you have added to the products2 sidebar only when you are in a post that has a category id of 9.